# Gradient Descent with derivative constraints

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

tl;dr: I need bound results for the derivative of some big honking function.

tfa: I am trying to solve an optimization problem:

Find a parameter vector $\theta$ so that $\sum_x \log f(\theta, x) \cdot y$ is minimized (it's a probability problem), subject to $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(\theta, x) \leq C$ for all $x$ in the input space ("soft bounds" would be fine... maybe a monte-carlo sampling procedure is relevant...?)

Note that the """subject to $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(\theta, x) \leq C$ for all $x$ in the input space""" bit is the hard part.

My problem is that estimating the derivative of $f$ at a point $x$ is expensive, and my input space is really, really, really big.  In fact, just computing $f(\theta, x)$ on some "fine" grid across my input space would be prohibitively expensive.  Are there some handy theorems that may be of use here (even if they are only applicable to certain classes of functions)?

We may be able to make some simplifying assumptions about $f$, such as convexity, so I am interested in any results that may be even tenuously related.

The result in [[1]](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2039474?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) may be of use.  It's for real-valued functions but probably generalizes (note that $f$ is vector-valued)

I'm not an expert in the fields of either functional analysis or numerical methods, and I am mostly hoping that people who are experts will be like "Oh yeah, so-and-so proved this thing in 1923.  Check out some classic text".

[1] Shaffer, Dorothy Browne. "On bounds for the derivative of analytic functions." Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society 37.2 (1973): 517-520.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You are trying to find an algorithm to optimize with derivative constraints? What use would bounds on the derivative be?

Comment: And what is $y?$

Comment: And what is a "honking big function"? Are you actually trying to implement this?

Comment: $\sum_x \log f(\theta, x) \cdot y$ is over $x$ and $y$ in our sample data.  $x$ are from the input space of $f$, $y$ are from the output space.

Comment: Yes, the goal is to create a real-world tractable problem.  So the options are 1) theoretical bounds on $df$ given some properties of $f$, such as in [1], or 2) "soft" bounds on $df$ given some sampling procedure on which I compute $df$ on a reasonably sized sample.

Comment: ...where what we mean by "reasonably sized" is up for discussion, but should be smaller than taking an $\epsilon$ grid over the input space.

Comment: What good would having a bound on the derivatives do you? (unless you knew *a priori* that they were all smaller than $C?$). Also, what do you mean that $y$ is from the output space. Is $y = f(x, \theta)?$

Comment: And how complicated *is* your function?

Comment: "honking big" means neural-network-sized, so $[0,1]^{10000}$ is the order of the input space.  So a $0.01$ grid would be $100^{10000}$ points $>>>>>$ the number of atoms in the universe.

Comment: $f$ should be locally continuous almost everywhere.  There might be some "jump" discontinuities.  The goal with the derivative bound is to obtain a result that if $|x-x'|<m$, then $|f(x)-f(x')|<M$, where, vaguely, if $m$ is small then $M$ should be small.

Comment: Why is that useful? And if the function has jump discontinuities, the result you want is certainly false...

Comment: Agreed.  Scratch the jump discontinuities, $f$ is a long series of compositions of simpler functions and I thought for a bit that one of those functions might not be continuous.  Just matplotlib'd it for a simple case and it is not discontinuous.  So $f$ is continuous everywhere and differentiable almost everywhere.  The derivative definitely DOES have jump discontinuities, but they are bounded, as in $dg_i < 1$ for every $g_i$ where $f = g_0 \circ g_1 .... g_n$

Comment: I suppose that may be my bounding result right there... :)

Comment: Even so, there may still be some monte-carlo result to get better bounds up to some probability.  Maybe?

Comment: The $|x−x′|<m \rightarrow |f(x)−f(x′)|<M$ is the end goal.  Currently, there is an overfitting problem with the model and inputs "near" the training inputs are giving wildly different outputs.  We would like it if $f$ was not allowed to "move so fast" in some sense.

Comment: My suggestion is to optimize $f +\alpha |\nabla(x)|^2.$ You can compute the gradient efficiently using automatic differentiation technology (ad or autograd in Python).

Comment: over what set of $x$?  If I just use the training input set, then this is insufficient, since the problem is what happens as we move away from those points...

Comment: Your function is a combination of elementary functions, so you can optimize it over the whole space (and, of course, you can use stochastic gradients instead of actual gradients).

Comment: Hmmm... by $f + \alpha| \nabla x |^2$ I think you mean $\sum_x \log f(\theta, x) \cdot y + \alpha| J(f(\theta, x)) |^2$, to penalize the size of the Jacobian.  Anyhoo, the original objective is being optimized over $x$ in the training dataset.  The $\alpha|J(f(\theta,x))|^2$ should be small at $x$ everywhere.  As such, I'm not sure how this new objective should work.  The first half of the objective only makes sense at the training points (because of $y$)...

Comment: I am reading about stochastic gradient descent now, though.  Thanks for the direction.

Comment: Ahhhhh.... The $\alpha|J(f(\theta,x))|^2$ is a fixed quantity that has a closed form over the space, because it's a composition of elementary functions!

Comment: A buzzword I've heard recently for stochastic gradient descent is "Bayesian optimization for hyperparameter tuning." Might be worth giving that a google. Also, I wonder if you can think of $\alpha$ as a Lagrange multiplier?

Comment: @Neal I've actually had the "Lagrange multiplier" thunk about regularization methods in general.  It was only ever just a passing thought though.  Let me know if you find anything.  :)